# Visual Force page disabling a field on submission make the page refresh

Tags: javascript

Currently  I have form that I create multiple tables in it when is renders. if I add this function which will disable a field for entering quantity , it will refreshes the page when I click on the submit button

```
function disablingx(){
       var x = $.grep($(".prodName"), function(arrayElement, index){
                                return $(arrayElement).html() === 'Test';
        });

       var xx = $(x).parent().parent().find("input[id*='hardItemQty']");
       xx.attr("disabled",true); 


    }
```

It is supposed to find a row of an element in the page then find the quantity field of that specific one and disables it.

Comment: You might get better feedback if you include your markup. This sort of functionality might also be better served by using the built-in tag attributes available to you.

Comment: @AdrianLarson yes I figured its not a good Idea to use that, but for everyone out there facing same problem I am doing this xx.css({"pointer-events": "none" , "color" :"gray" });

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: @RahulSharma When I used disabled true with javascript it wouldnt let me go to the next page, it would just refresh the page... the javascript didnt have any problem. Salesforce is acting up in this case and I am not sure why